# Which window manager is most similar to MS Windows?

Tags: software-recommendation, window-manager

Background:

I'm changing a lot of desktop environments every day, and i'd like to some uniformity between them to keep my productivity up.

So, which window-manager can be installed in Ubuntu that has most similar functionality, usability to ms-Windows?

e.g.: open/save file dialog, alt-tab behavior, main key bindings.

Is there such a window manager?

Comment: You can try them all; [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) and [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download); from a live CD/DVD or USB stick without installing.  Try them out and install the one you like best.

Comment: You could also just use windows if it's windows functionality you want.

Answer (score 6):

There may be others but I'd say you'd struggle to find anything better for your purpose than KDE.

- You start with something that looks most like Windows already.
- You can customise just about everything, very easily.
- There are even themes that make it look like Windows.
- Window-switchers (alt-tab) are configurable too.

---

On a slightly different note: I have found that it does sometimes help to keep things different if they operate differently. Stuff like having the minimise/maximise/close buttons in the same place makes sense but if your launchers *work* differently, keeping them visually disparate means you won't accidentally do the wrong thing.

Comment: +1 for keeping things different.  I often get frustrated when a Linux command does  not work in Windows: Several years ago it was DOS commands not working in Linux.  Having the desktops visually different reminds you which system you are using.