# Reskin Ubuntu to other OS (MS Windows, Android) Muscle Memory

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, windows-10, android, gui

I know there was a linux OS that was very similar to windows, so allow users to switch from windows more easily...

As one of the issues with non-technical users is learning the command line or Graphical User Interfaces, is it possible to reskin Ubuntu to behave like Windows 10/7/11 or Andriod?

I.e. make the behaviour of the linux OS match windows closely so you have to relearn very little?

Related Questions:

[Which window manager is most similar to MS Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292496/which-window-manager-is-most-similar-to-ms-windows)

Comment: Change the tags to the best ones, just guessing at present

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This sort of question is excessively broad, so will likely not receive specific-enough answers for what’s implied but not written in the question. If you’re looking for Windows-like GUIs, consider a KDE-based distribution like Kubuntu. Linux Mint is also a common choice for people who are familiar with Windows, though not supported on this site. For 99% of situations, though, people can work completely via a GUI when using Linux. My mother has never once used the Terminal in all her years with Ubuntu.

Comment: @matigo even now?
I appreciate this bit is too broad, How much effort has been done to make on boarding new windows users easier?

Comment: @matigo it is more that the behaviour of the linux OS will match windows closely so you have to relearn very little

Comment: I don’t know how much (or little) you know about Windows, so I cannot answer your question. This is why I’m using comments  That said, many of the keyboard shortcuts one uses in Windows can be found in Linux (and MacOS and BSD and Solaris), many of the GUI patterns are the same, many of the ghastly font choices in niche applications are the same, and many of the arguments from soapbox preachers about the benefits of “the one, true OS” — regardless of which one it is — are the same. At the end of the day, *you* are the one who needs to investigate and make the best decision for your needs.

Comment: @matigo ok, just be good if there was a how to do guides on making popular and patched linux systems work like windows so you just plug and play as far as possible...

Lot of committed technical users but wondering about the people with very low computer literacy...

Comment: @maskin *"How much effort has been done to make on boarding new windows users easier?"* -- There *may* be a chance you misunderstand this site.  AU isn't sponsored by or monitored by Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu).  We're just a community of users who attempt to help each other out.  However, we have to do it within the "question-and-answer" framework here on Stack Exchange.  As mentioned in the [help](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask), *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*  And yes, there have been entire books on that topic ;-).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Sorry, figured this was ok

Comment: @matigo Can you add your comments as an answer, aka kbuntu that you family member can actually use, and maybe we could get some votes on the easiest Ubuntu flavours

Comment: @maskin No worries.  And while I didn't vote to close it, I'm just attempting to explain why others probably did.  However, no answers can be added to a question that has been closed.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks and FFS on closing

Answer (score 1):

If you want Windows-like appearance, then gather a like-minded team and create/contribute that software. That's how Ubuntu works. We won't organize your team for you. We won't write your software for you.

Our philosophy is that folks should use the OS that they want to use. If they want to use Windows, then they should use Windows. If they want to use Ubuntu, then they should use Ubuntu.

Ubuntu is Open Source. Folks who want an orientation on robotics and games and tiny devices and massive enterprises and their favorite desktop environments and many more interests have contributed software and improvements to Ubuntu. A windows-like appearance seems like another interest, so recruit your team of volunteers to make that happen.

Comment: Sorry but making a fork isn't really an answer as I'm looking for something that's going to be patched, have enough people, so reuse an existing distro...
Not: if you don't like Ubuntu, make something yourself! :-( :-)

I am looking to use the existing community and make Ubuntu easier for windows 10 users to adopt, particularly given the lack of support for existing machines for Windows 11...

Comment: What your question proposes seems far more complex than a few simple patches. You will need to do a lot of ongoing testing and maintenance. One new-user generally lacks the skills and the available time to do all of that alone. Making a team and then a respin (not a fork) is exactly the answer that KDE users, Cinnamon users, LXDE users, XFCE users, MATE users, and others have followed. It is unclear how your vision is different. Next time, put that in the question. A better, clearer question will lead to more useful answers.